# Check if text field in collectionView is empty

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view (`CollectionViewController`) with 3 cells (each cell has it's own class). In the first cell (`TextCell`) I have a text field and a button (`nextButton`). When I press the button I want to check if the text field is empty or not. If it's not empty, I want to switch to the second cell.

CollectionViewController:

```
let textCell = TextCell()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.cellId, for: indexPath)

    // TextCell
    if indexPath.item == 0 {

        let tCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: textCellId, for: indexPath)
            let nextButton = textCell.nextButton
                nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleNextButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return tCell
    }
    return cell
}


//Handle Action

@objc func handleNextButton() {
    let text = textCell.TextField.text

    if text?.isEmpty == false {
        scrollToIndex(menuIndex: 1)
    } else {
        print("Text field is empty.")
    }
}
```

The problem is that every time i check if the text field is empty or not, it say's it is empty although it's not.

Comment: Add the line **print ("The text is: \(text)")** just before your if statement... This will surely make you see what is wrong

Comment: AHHHH - You don't use your cell correctly.. I'll post an answer in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - **Remove** the next line, It's not needed and is definitely wrong!

```
let textCell = TextCell()
```

Now **replace** your func with that:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // TextCell
    if indexPath.item == 0 {

        let tCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: textCellId, for: indexPath) as! TextCell
            let nextButton = tCell.nextButton
                nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleNextButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return tCell
    }

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.cellId, for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

**And The Handler**

```
//Handle Action
@objc func handleNextButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let tCell = sender.superview as! TextCell
    let text = tCell.TextField.text

    if text?.isEmpty == false {
        scrollToIndex(menuIndex: 1)
    } else {
        print("Text field is empty.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i haven't seen your answer. But thanks I'll try that. Let you know if it worked. Could take some time, I'm currently in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

To identify whether the `UITextField` inside `UICollectionViewCell` is empty or not, you need to pass index position when button is clicked. To pass index position you can use tag. By using tag you can get clicked index position. After getting position, you can access elements from current index position by using  cellForItemAtIndexPath . You can find the particular index position UITextField is empty or not using the fetched cell reference

In Your  `cellForItemAt`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

      if indexPath.item  == 0{
         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER", for: indexPath) as!  YOUR_UICOLLECTIONVIEW_CELL
                    cell.nextBtn.tag = indexPath.item
                    cell.nextBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleNextButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

          return cell
       } else {
              ///use your other cells here
       }
}
```

In your ViewController

```
func handleNextButton(_ sender:UIButton){
  let indexPath = IndexPath(item:sender.tag,section:0)
  let cell = YOUR_COLLECTIONVIEW.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! YOUR_UICOLLECTIONVIEW_CELL
  if cell.txtFld.text == "" {
    print("TextField is empty")
   } else {
   print("TextField not empty")
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you